# Typescript Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 which module system for importing separate ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, es6-module-loader

In visual studio I've created a Typescript project with several classes declared in the default app.ts files. Now I'd like to begin separating those classes into separate .ts file. I'm having difficulty understanding which module loading system is recommended for this project type.

[image]

I've selected ES6 so that I can use syntax for asyc/await:

[image: ts project props]

I've added a new Test.ts file with an exported Test type declaration:

```
export class Test {

}
```

back in my app.ts I'm creating an instance of this type:

```
window.onload = async () => {
    let test = new Test();
}
```

Visual Studio offers to add an import for it:

```
import {Test} from "Test";
```

Now, when I run the solution in Chrome I get the following console message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I realize that chrome isn't "import" aware. Could someone provide a suggestion of how I can get imports to work in this VS 2015 environment. Do I need to take another module system and if so how do I add support of loading separate .ts files?

Edit:
I've seen examples using this syntax:

```
/// <reference path="Test.ts" />
```

but it doesn't work to compile-time resolve the type and I gather that is a deprecated approach.

Also, as I look at the sources tab in Chrome, I can see what I think is transpilation from my source to (ES5?):

```
window.onload = () => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
```

but I also see the "class" keyword which I did not expect so I'm not exactly certain why certain transforms are happening or not. i.e. async to __awaiter (supported), class (not transpiled and supported), import (not transformed and not supported.)

**Edit**
I followed the [project](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html)

Using a webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
      filename: './dist/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
      // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
      extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
          { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
      ]
  }
}
```

but I seem to have the same problem that the import statement copied verbatim and is not transformed in the ES5 output to a loader that the browser understands:

```
import {Test} from "./Test";
```

[image]

Comment: Too long for an SO response but TL;DR: use external modules and webpack. Check this [excellent resource](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html)

Comment: Excellent - I didn't even realize there was a distinction for browser and non-browser based ts.

Comment: Set up a project as specified in that link, but I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bruno for putting me on the correct track. What allowed my separate .ts files to be transpiled down to a single ES5 js file was to add babel-loader.

First by installing it into the node_modules:

```
npm install babel-loader
```

And then adding the loader reference to my tsconfig.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
      filename: './dist/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
      // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
      extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
          { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader"}
      ]
  }
}
```

Now, import statements in the ts files are transpiled to babel-loader syntax